# How to find the exact value of this series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I found this on wolfram alpha :

[image]
How does wolfram evaluate this series?  How to proof that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{2n}+...+\frac{1}{n^2}\right)^2= \frac{17\pi^4}{360} $$ ?
Thanks in advance.